# Why aren't real time operating systems mainstream

Tags: concurrency, operating-system

Anecdotally, RTOS's are supposed to be a good thing for concurrent systems **so why don't RTOS dominate the OS market?**

I don't know anyting about them and am curious why, as an industry, we're not more 'in the loop' when it comes to RTOS.

ps, if I wanted to start playing, can you recommend a good, modern OS to get started doing benchmarks against?

Comment: Can you elaborate why this was closed as off topic?

Comment: Can you suggest how I could rephrase this to get it reopened? How would I go about getting it reopened (assuming its rephrased)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an RTOS is actually quite complex. To be able to guaratee real time behaviour requires research in advance on the processes and threads you want to use, and which priorities to assign. For this reason, using a non-RT OS is often simpler, especially when upfront the number of applications and type of applications is unknown.

Also, when doing research in advance, it is not as simple as assigning some priorities to threads, as advanced problems can occur like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_starvation
and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inversion.

Yet, in some situations when you want to be able to guaratee RT behaviour, RTOSes can be really usefull. Some good free RTOSes are FreeRTOS for on embedded devices and QNX for destop PCs